# Dynamically changing the layout in the MainActivity

Tags: android

I'm working on an Android app about mobile network. I can get the serving cell information. I display the information in a `CardView`, but I have a different layout for the `CardView` for each technology (2G, 3G, 4G). 
What I want to know is how should I code this?

Should I create 3 `Fragments` and update the `MainActivity` with the good fragment when the radio technology changes? Is there a cleaner way to do this? It feels like it will take a lot of files if I do it like this.

Thanks

Comment: if you have different layouts then it is better to go with fragments and number of files does not matter, as performance will not be affected if you use more number of files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use for example a LinearLayout which holds your content. Each time, you want to change the content (the technology changes in your case) you call `RemoveAllViews` on that LinearLayout, inflate your new technology, and add this new View to your LinearLayout.